# Proposed: burninate [tables] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-clean-up

I draw your attention to the [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) tag. Currently, there are 20 questions. They cover subjects like:

- displaying data in Google Sheets
- modifying tables in OneNote
- fetching an HTML table with IMPORTHTML() in Google Sheets
- deleting an HTML table in a Gmail message
- creating a table view in draw.io
- working with display tables in Google Docs
- how to insert an HTML table in a variety of web-based message or document apps

Using the [criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/21960):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   **No**. While each is referencing a two-dimensional grid of information, the context is different each time.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   **Not really**. While tables are sometimes present in web applications, there is no context without other tags. No one is an expert on "tables".
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   **No**.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   **Definitely not**. It cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question and has no context without other tags.

I put forth that this tag should be *burninated*.

---

Well, there are no objections, so this seems safe to move forward on. Let's not flood the front page, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All uses of this tag have been removed. The tag itself will be removed overnight.